# Uploaded an image using `file_put_contents` with 0 bytes (empty)?

Tags: php, upload, file-get-contents

I've downloaded an image using `file_get_contents` from URL then uploaded it to my website using `file_put_contents`, the image appears in the specified directory, however it has the size of zero. I've changed the permissions to 777 in this directory and the parent directories, but nothing happened.

I already tried the same code in the localhost, and it worked perfectly.

By the way, I'm using a joomla website and a component called RSform Pro, it is used for creating forms and gives an area where you can edit the POST data before saving it in the database. Here's the code.

```
$content = file_get_contents($_POST['image_url']);

$date = date ('d-m-Y_h-m-i');   $random = rand(0,1000);
$name = 'mysite_'.$date.$random.'.png';

$filename = '/home/mysite/images/'.$name;

file_put_contents($filename, $content);
```

Comment: Make sure there is actually Data from `file_get_contents` returned.

Comment: @ChristophWinkler I already tried the code in the localhost and it worked fine, the image was uploaded.

Comment: @Sarah Obviously is something different to your local configuration. Check if data is returned from `file_get_contents` to determine which part (download/saving) is not working.

Comment: Make sure you can see all PHP errors: `ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the top of your script. Also you should see what you get from `echo ini_get('allow_url_fopen');`, I suspect you may find it is disabled.

Comment: And your format string passed to date is wrong, I suspect - you probably meant `d-m-Y_h-i-s`, although `Y-m-d_H-i-s` would make the most sense, I feel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where I start, there is so much wrong this code...

1. You have to check the return value of file_get_contents and ensure your host allows retriving remote data (allow_url_fopen set to On in php.ini)
2. After that, everything else is awfully wrong and punches a security hole in your application.The result you store in the $content variable must be written to an unique temporary file, whose only correct way of generation is using the tempnam() function.
3. After issing file_put_contents to the filename generated by tempnam() and checking return values of the operation, you have to verify if the file is really a png image using php's fileinfo functions.
4. If the previous step succeeds then use rename() to move the file to permanent storage, using a name that is very unlikely to be repeated ever. for that use `$filename = hash('sha256', openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16)) . 'png'.` then store the resulting filename so it can be used to construct the links your application will show to users.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I checked the php.ini and it is set to ON.
However, the function `file_get_contents` returns nothing.